# Using LINQ to create pairs from two different list where the entries have same attribute

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of `Requests` and `Responses` who inherit from the abstract `AbstractLineModel` class. Both the responses and requests contain an ID (or not) named `RequestId`.

A `CallPair` contains a matching pair of `Request` and a `Response` and has the following constructor:

```
public AbstractLineModel _request { get; set; }
public AbstractLineModel _response { get; set; }

public CallPair(AbstractLineModel request, AbstractLineModel response)
{
    _request = request;
    _response = response;
}
```

I want to make a `List` of `CallPairs` where the `Request` with the same Id as the `Response` are matched in the `Callpair`. How to match the list of `Requests` and `Responses`?

What I tried is:

```
public void MatchCallPairs()
{
    // Finds request that have matching response
    var requestWithMatches = _requests
        .Where(req => _responses.All(res => res.RequestId == req.RequestId)).ToList();

    // Match the request to the response
    foreach (var req in requestWithMatches)
    {
        var resp = _responses.Where(res => res.RequestId == req.RequestId).FirstOrDefault();

        // And create the pairs
        _callPairs.Add(new CallPair(req, resp));
    }
}
```

but this returns an empty list.

Specifically,       `var requestWithMatches = _requests
                .Where(req => _responses.All(res => res.RequestId == req.RequestId)).ToList();` returns an empty list of requestsWithMatches.

Can someone help me out with this algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just join both sequences on RequestId and create CallPair from joined items:

```
 var requestWithMatches = from req in _requests
                          join resp in _responses
                             on req.RequestId equals resp.RequestId
                          select new CallPair(req, resp);
```

Comment: Hmm this creates a very long list. I have 400 responses and requests so I expect 200 pairs maximum. This creates about 14000 matches.

Comment: Ah I see it also matches empty strings, but still way too many.

Comment: If I do             `var requestWithMatches = (from req in _requests
                                      join resp in _responses
                                         on req.RequestId equals resp.RequestId
                                         where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.RequestId)
                                      select new CallPair(req, resp) );` I get around 80 values from the 400. Still strange that if I do not do that I get 4000 from 400. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If I want to select the responses and requests that aren't matched and put them into a list, how do I go about doing that? I.e., the opposite of this query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enumerable.Join` for this:

```
public void MatchCallPairs()
{
    // Finds request that have matching response
    var requestWithMatches = from req in _requests
                             join resp in _responses
                             on req.RequestId equals resp.RequestId
                             select new CallPair(req, resp);
    _callPairs =  requestWithMatches.ToList();
}
```

Apart from the fact that this is more efficient, your code was incorrect:

```
_responses.All(res => res.RequestId == req.RequestId)
```

since that checks if `All` responses' `RequestId` are the same.

Comment: You don't need the second select. Just put the projection in the first declaration. Also, ToList isn't necessarily called for here. Since we don't know the flavor of LINQ, it may not be necessary at all.

Comment: @JimWooley: good point, edited my answer accordingly. Acc. to the `ToList`, that's what OP is doing above since he's adding them to a list.

Comment: Is there a better datatype to use than a list to store the `Request` and `Response` objects?