# How to match all objects from two lists into pairs of two based on proximity of DateTime values

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

I have two lists of `Requests` and `Responses` who inherit from the abstract `AbstractLineModel` class. Both the responses and requests contain a DateTime (or not) named `DateTime`, `MethodName`, and a `GUID`.

A `CallPair` contains a matching pair of `Request` and a `Response`:

```
public class CallPair
{
    public AbstractLineModel _request { get; set; }
    public AbstractLineModel _response { get; set; }

    public CallPair(AbstractLineModel request, AbstractLineModel response)
    {
        _request = request;
        _response = response;
    }
}
```

The class `CallPairOrganizer` organizes the calls into the following lists:

```
public class CallPairOrganizer
{
    // List of requests and matching responses
    private List<CallPair> _callPairs = new List<CallPair>();
    private List<AbstractLineModel> _lines = new List<AbstractLineModel>();
    private List<AbstractLineModel> _requests = new List<AbstractLineModel>();
    private List<AbstractLineModel> _responses = new List<AbstractLineModel>();
    private List<AbstractLineModel> _unmatchedRequests = new List<AbstractLineModel>();
    private List<AbstractLineModel> _unmatchedResponses = new List<AbstractLineModel>();
}
```

These are two methods of the `CallPairOrganizer` class: (1) With the help of an earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045577/using-linq-to-create-pairs-from-two-different-list-where-the-entries-have-same-a#22045682) I have made a `List` of `CallPairs` where the `Request` with the same `GUID` as the `Response` are matched in the `Callpair`:

```
public void MatchCallPairsByRequestId()
{
    // Finds request that have matching response based on RequestId and create 
    // callpair
    _callPairs = _requests.Distinct().Where(req => !string.IsNullOrEmpty
                     (req.RequestId))
         .Join(_responses.Distinct(),
               req => req.RequestId,
               resp => resp.RequestId,
               (req, resp) => new CallPair(req, resp)).ToList();

    CollectUnmatchedCalls();
}
```

And (2) I collect all unmatched requests and responses as follows:

```
public void CollectUnmatchedCalls()
{
    _unmatchedRequests = 
         _requests.Except(_callPairs.Select(cp => cp._request)).ToList();
    _unmatchedResponses = _responses.Except(_callPairs.Select(cp => 
           cp._response)).ToList();
}
```

This works. The next step is to compare the unmatched requests and responses and sort them based on DateTime property *if* they are of the same `MethodName`. If a request and response are closest to each other I want to match them into a `CallPair`.

With this part I have a difficult time trying to figure out what algorithm/linq to use. I hope someone can provide me with insights on how to accomplish this task of matching a request with response of the same `MethodName` if they are close to each other based on DateTime.

Comment: You need to spend some more time defining your matching behavior. Say you've got 1:00, 1:15, 1:25, 1:40. Do you match 1:00 to 1:15 because it's closer to 1:00 than any other times? If so, then can you still match up 1:15 and 1:25, or is 1:15 "taken" by the previous match?

Comment: A bit different but I would go about this with a SortSet

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I think that we need to keep this method of sorting on time as a last resort and I need to find a method that matches requests and responses on other properties first (there is more information that I did not post here in the requests and responses that might allow to match them). I do think I will use the 'taken' approach as the last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to find the "closest" response, to a request?

```
//just some objects for me to play with
var requests =  Enumerable.Range(1).Select(i => new { Time = DateTime.Now, Method = "blah" }).ToList();
var responses =  Enumerable.Range(1).Select(i => new { Time = DateTime.Now, Method = "blah" }).ToList();

foreach (var req in requests)
{
    //In all of the responses - find the one that happened soonest after the request (with the same method name)
    var closestResponse = responses
        .Where(resp => resp.Method == req.Method)
        .OrderBy(resp => resp.Time - req.Time)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    //No more responses - exit
    if(closestResponse == null)
        break;

    responses.Remove(closestResponse);

    //make new call pair, with the closest rseponse
}
```

Comment: Exactly! I will check this on Monday when I'm back at my code. :-) the code does exactly what I said haha, easiest approach and I'm sure it will work. Thanks a bunch.